# iOS Objective-C how to use a predicate to search a string array for multiple non-sequential keywords?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsstring, nspredicate

I'm using the following code to do a search of an array, returning items that contain parts of the search query. This works well when a search query is a single word or part of a word:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"comment.text CONTAINS [cd] %@ ",_searchQuery];
NSArray *result = [_sourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

**How can I expand my predicate to take a search query with multiple words and return results that contain all of the words in query?**

For example:

- Text to search "apples and oranges are fruits"
- Query: "apple fruit"
- The current predicate will not match this query to the text.
- How to modify the predicate to match the text to search to that query?

Comment: You can combine predicates, or use just `comment.text CONTAINS [cd] apple AND comment.Text CONTAINS [cd] fruit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code enumerates the words in `_searchQuery` creating a predicate for each, then combines them into an `NSCompoundPredicate` using `AND`:

```
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray new];
[_searchQuery enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, _searchQuery.length)
                                 options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                              usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                           NSPredicate *subpredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"comment.text CONTAINS [cd] %@ ",substring];
                           [subpredicates addObject:subpredicate];
                       }];

NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
NSArray *result = [_sourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order of your keywords is important to you, you can use a regular expression to do the job:

```
NSArray *const source = @[@"apples and oranges are fruits"];

static NSString *const separator = @".*";
NSArray *const keywords = @[@"apples", @"oranges"];
NSString *const pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", separator, [keywords componentsJoinedByString:separator], separator];
NSPredicate *const predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self MATCHES %@", pattern];

NSArray *const filtered = [source filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Otherwise you can just `OR` a couple `CONTAINS` together, like @Larme suggested.

Comment: I think the AND predicate is better, because regular expression still expects words to be in a certain order. This would work for some applications, but I want more google search like behavior.